# Replacement for rowid in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, rowid

I have an Oracle select that I need to execute in SQL Server (the table is exported from an Oracle database to a SQL Server database). I can replace `nvl` with `isnull` and decode with case I guess, but how to deal with the `rowid` in this specific case?

```
select sum(
  nvl(
    (select sum(b.restsaldo) from reskontro.erkrysskid b
    where 1=1
    and b.fakturanr = a.fakturanr
    and b.kundenr = a.kundenr
    and b.resknr = b.resknr
    and a.rowid = decode(a.reskfunknr,31,a.rowid,b.rowid)
    and nvl(b.restsaldo,0) <> 0
    and b.krysskidid <= a.krysskidid
    and not exists (select * from reskontro.erkrysskid c
      where b.kundenr = c.kundenr
      and b.resknr = c.resknr
      and a.resklinr < c.resklinr
      and a.krysskidid < c.krysskidid
      and b.fakturanr = c.fakturanr
      and c.reskfunknr in (31,75)
      and nvl(c.attfort,-1) = -1)
      ),0
    )
) as restsaldo from reskontro.erkrysskid a 
where 1=1
and a.kundenr = 1 
and a.resknr = 1
```

Comment: The answer should depend on the data type for the original column `a.rowid`. You did not share what data type that column does have.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: To convert the Oracle `DECODE` expression to T-SQL, use a `CASE` expression: `CASE WHEN a.reskfunknr = 31 THEN a.rowid ELSE b.rowid END`

Comment: Some hints: 1) Get rid of these meaningless 1=1 conditions, they make the queries long and bad to read. 2) Do not use non-standard SQL functions when standard SQL functions can do the same. As you are just noticing by asking this question, this causes unnecessary work when changing the DBMS. So ISNULL is as bad as NVL. Just use COALESCE. 3) Ask a specific, meaningful question and explain exactly what you want to know. "How to deal with" is very unprecise.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't have a [ROWID pseudo column](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROWID-Pseudocolumn.html#GUID-F6E0FBD2-983C-495D-9856-5E113A17FAF1).  In Oracle this is being used in the context of a self-join to determine if the two rows being joined are the *same row*.  In SQL Server simply compare the table's key columns instead.

eg, if the table has a key on a Id column, use

```
and a.Id = case when a.reskfunknr = 31 then a.Id else b.Id end
```